# How to enable backticks in mysql codeigniter active record

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I try codeigniter active record, it give me error when i try to update field named Dec (Jan - Nov was fine before)...

This is my code

```
        $this->db->set($month,"$month+$tax", FALSE);
        $this->db->set('total_yearly',"total_yearly+$tax", FALSE);
        $this->db->where(array('tax_category' => $tax_category));
        $this->db->update($nama_table);
```

And the query return like this

```
UPDATE `tax` SET Dec = Dec+10000, total_yearly = total_yearly+10000 WHERE `tax_category` = 'Hotel' AND `year` = '2017'
```

Error message

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'Dec = Dec+2479, total_yearly = total_yearly+2479 WHERE
>   `tax_category` = 'Hotel' AN' at line 1

Any solution? i have tried to add backticks on query, but the result still backtick is removed, or maybe i didnt do it well.

Thanks

Comment: is below query is working for you.

Comment: u can change like this and try $this->db->set($month,"'$month+$tax'", FALSE);

Comment: @itsme, still doesnt work, query message return Dec = 'Dec+10000'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that "DEC" is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html).  Throw some backticks around the field names in your SET clause so the query reads:

```
UPDATE `tax` SET `Dec` = `Dec`+10000, `total_yearly` = `total_yearly`+10000 WHERE `tax_category` = 'Hotel' AND `year` = '2017'
```

Comment: I have tried with manual query like that, but still doesnt work, codeigniter remove the ( ` ).  and query result is still like this :

UPDATE `tax` SET Dec = Dec+10000, total_yearly = total_yearly+10000 WHERE `tax_category` = 'Hotel' AND `year` = '2017'

Comment: Problem solved, and thanks for giving me a keyword to learn that mysql have reserved word :)

Comment: I am a fan of prefixing my field names based on the table they are in (eg, mt_tax instead of tax), which also avoids keyword issues (who knows what the next keyword will be?-)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you :

remove third parameter `FALSE` to allow use backtick

`set()` will also accept an optional third parameter `($escape)`, that will prevent data from being escaped if set to `FALSE`.

```
$this->db->set($month,$month.'+'.$tax);
$this->db->set('total_yearly',"total_yearly+".$tax);
$this->db->where(array('tax_category' => $tax_category));
$this->db->update($nama_table);
```

read more : 
https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#updating-data

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing :

```
$this->db->set($month,"$month+$tax", FALSE);
```

with :

```
$this->db->set("`$month`","`$month`+$tax", FALSE);
```

to force adding the backticks